# What is the maximum amount of memory that can be allocated to a 32-bit Cent OS 6.5 Xen server virtual machine?

Tags: xen

When I creating a 32-bit virtual machine with Cent OS 6.5 on Xen server 7.6, the following error is reported when the memory setting of the virtual machine exceeds 16G: the amount of physical memory allocated to this vm is greater than the total memory of its home server.

What is the maximum amount of memory that can be allocated to a 32-bit Cent OS 6.5 Xen server virtual machine?

[image]

Comment: For 32bit you can use (from OS) 4GB RAM. Of course you can use PAE, but it is supported from short list of apps

Comment: Xen host have  192G  memory.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [the XenServer 7.6 manual](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/legacy-archive/downloads/citrix-xenserver-7.6.pdf), the maximum amount of memory which can be allocated to a 32-bit CentOS 6.5 VM is 16GiB (see “Guest operating system support”; the CentOS 6.5 entry is on page 25). This would probably correspond to a value of 16384 in the “VM memory” field.

The error message is rather misleading, this has nothing to do with the amount of memory installed in the host.

Comment: That `MB` in the picture is also likely misleading. I doubt those are meant to be megabytes. More probably, those are mebibytes, in which case the maximum value would be 16 GiB == 16384 MiB == 17179.869184 MB.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt, thanks vey much !

Answer (score -1):

Andrew, you are overcommitting the memory. Which means, you are assigning more memory to the VM than the underlying host's memory.

Eg. The host has 32GB Memory  and you are assigning 40GB to the guest VM.

Workaround - Do check the host's memory and assign lesser memory to the VM. Why you should not assign higher/equal memory which is available - the hypervisor needs some memory to run. Also do check if any other VM is powered on and utilising the memory.

Comment: No, the OP isn’t overcommitting memory, the host has 192GiB of RAM.

Comment: As per my workaround - Andrew, need to check if there are any other VMs running (Monster VM) which is utilising higher RAM. @Andrew, what is the memory utilisation in the xen server?

Comment: Currently-allocated memory shouldn’t be a factor when creating the domain; it would only cause problems when starting it.